# Prototype copy vs Object.create() vs new

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was using inheritance and I noticed that there are three ways to get the same result. What's the difference?

```
function Animal(){
}

Animal.prototype.doThat = function() {
    document.write("Doing that");
}

function Bird(){
}

// This makes doThat() visible
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // Solution 1
// You can also do:
// Bird.prototype = new Animal(); // Solution 2
// Or:
// Bird.prototype = Animal.prototype; // Solution 3

var myVar = new Bird();
myVar.doThat();
```

As you can see I proposed three solution. Each one of them make the method doThat() visible.

If I comment all of them there is an error indeed.

If I decomment only one of them the program works.

So... what's really the difference between the three solution?

Answer (score 14):

> `Bird.prototype = Animal.prototype; // Solution 3`

Since this assigned `Animal.prototype` directly to `Bird.prototype`, all changes you make to the latter will also be reflected in `Animal` and all other classes that inherit from it.

For example:

```
Bird.prototype.fly = function() {
    console.log('I can fly.');
}

var some_animal = new Animal();
some_animal.fly(); // this will work
```

This is certainly not what you want. Not only will every method of this subclass available for other subclasses, but if you override parent methods in subclasses, the subclass that was defined last will override the changes of the other subclasses.

In your question title you seem to refer to this as "prototype copy". This is not correct, since no copy is created. `Animal.prototype` and `Bird.prototype` will refer to one and the same object.

---

> `Bird.prototype = new Animal(); // Solution 2`

This has been a common way to setup inheritance for a long time but it has two major drawbacks:

- If `Animal` requires arguments, which do you pass? Passing random, meaningless arguments just to make the function call work seems to be bad design.
- `Animal` might have side effects, like increasing an instance counter, but in this moment you actually didn't create a new instance (or don't want to), you just wanted to setup the inheritance.

---

> `Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // Solution 1`

That's the way you should do it now ([until a better solution comes](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes)). All you really want to do is hook up `Animal`'s prototype into the prototype chain of `Bird`. It avoids all the drawbacks of the previous solutions.

To make it work properly though, you also have to call the `Animal` constructor inside the `Bird` constructor. It's like a call to `super` in other programming languages:

```
function Bird(){
    Animal.call(this);
}
```

This ensure that any commands/changes made to a new `Animal` instance are applied to the new `Bird` instance.

It is also good practice to assign the correct value to the `constructor` property of the prototype. It usually refers to the function the prototype "belongs to", but in all of the solutions above, `Bird.prototype.constructor` will refer to `Animal`. So we have to do:

```
Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;
```

This property is not used internally, so you only *have to* do this if your own code relies on it. However, if you create a library to be used by others, they will probably expect the property to have to correct value.

Comment: @Rikonator: You don't *have to* unless your code depends on it. It is not used internally, so it is not required. Though I think it is good practice. Will update.

Comment: @Rikonator No, every object has a constructor function, the constructor for Bird is pinned at the Bird object. Of course, since prototype is also an object, it too, has a constructor function, which you do not use normally.

Comment: @ghost23: No, the `constructor` property is always inherited from the prototype. It is not a property of the instance itself.

Comment: @FelixKling .. for `Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); ` will effects on changing `Animal.prototype` properties . I recommend to use jQuery extend `Bird.prototype = jQuery.extend( true, {}, Animal.prototype );` which gives exact copy

Comment: @Felix Kling I have my doubts about that. Made a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJ4fx/

Comment: @rab: I don't understand what you mean. `Object.create` creates a new object that inherits from `Animal.prototype`. Any changes you make to that object won't have any impact on `Animal.prototype`.

Comment: @ghost23: Maybe I misunderstood you, I don't know. I meant that an instance's `constructor` property (i.e. `obj.constructor`) is inherited from the prototype and usually (obviously by the name) refers to the instance's constructor function. But by setting the inheritance in any of the ways above, the constructor property will refer to the parent function (through inheritance).

Comment: @rab: Ah, but that is to be expected. You usually want that any changes made to the parent prototype are reflected in all children. That's the power of prototype inheritance. If you don't want that, then yes, you have to create a copy. But that's the exception.

Comment: document.write(Bird.prototype.constructor); // Prints animal
Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;
document.write(Bird.prototype.constructor); // Prints bird
document.write(Animal.prototype.constructor); // Prints animal    But why should I change a constructor property if it's not used internally?

Comment: @user1883212: It's more of a correction than a change. And I tried to outline the reasons in my answer: 1) If your code depends on it. 2) If you want to make your code available to others.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't understand why `Animal.call(this)` is needed. The explanation afterwards _This ensure that any commands/changes made to a new `Animal` instance are applied to the new `Bird` instance._ This also doesn't make sense to me. Could you clarify?

Comment: @inthenameofmusik: since a bird is an animal, we have to make sure that the initializing procedure for every animal (the `Animal` function) is also applied to the bird instance. That's what that line is doing.

Comment: @AvinashAgrawal: yes, it’s needed, assuming `Animal` actually contains some initialization logic. `Animal` is a function, not a prototype.

Comment: @FelixKling but When we say Object.create(Animal.prototype) where does we initializing Animal, what we want is just it's prototype. Now incase Animal.prototype has a method which refers to "this". In this case this will become the child object. Happy to discuss more

Comment: @AvinashAgrawal: `Animal.call(this)` is basically the same as calling `super()`, i.e. we are calling the parent constructor that we are inheriting from. That’s import because the methods defined on the prototype might depend on state that is initialized in the constructor. Example: `function Foo() { this.x = 42; } Foo.prototype.alert = function() { console.log(this.x);}; function Bar() {}; Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype); new Bar().alert();`.  Because we are not calling `Foo.call(this)`, `alert()` will log `undefined`, not `42`.

Comment: @FelixKling Your explanation is correct in a sense but what if `function Foo(param) { this.x = param; } ` accepts a param calling super() , then calling alert() will yield undefined. When I am assigning prototype of class 1 to class 2 what I am interested in only helper functions. Now with your example `let barObj = new Bar(); barObj.x = 42 ; barObj.alert() ` will yield 42.

Comment: @AvinashAgrawal: *”what I am interested in only helper functions”* that’s your specific use case then. If you know that you don’t have to call the parent constructor then don’t. I’m talking about the general case. My example was simple. `Foo` could also perform some very complex initialization that is is difficult to replicate or you might not know what `Foo` is doing at all (e.g. built in constructors like `Array`). Again, you can do whatever you want. I’m just saying what is the most correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use **Solution 1** or **Solution 2**, but you **should not** use **Solution 3**.

The reason is when you do `Bird.prototype = Animal.prototype;`, every change on `Bird.prototype` will also affect `Animal.prototype`, because they the same object.

For example, you attach a method on `Bird.prototype`, then the method will also works on `Animal`, which will not be what you want.