# Is there any meaningful usecase to assign an instance of one function-object to the prototype-attribute of another function-object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any reason why I should assign a new instance of one function-object to the prototype-attribute of another function-object? Would it represent some kind of inheritance mechanism?

```
function Foo() {}
function Bar() {}
new Bar() instanceof Bar; // true
new Bar() instanceof Foo; // false

// assign instance of Foo to Bar.prototype:
Bar.prototype = new Foo();

// that results in: 
new Bar() instanceof Bar; // true
new Bar() instanceof Foo; // true
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100682/218196 wrt inheritance. While the specific approach is not good, yes, this is how you would setup inheritance/a prototype chain. `class A extends B {}` does something similar under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has prototypal inheritance. Objects can inherit other objects. This basically means that you can "see" properties of the parent object¹ on the child:

```
  const parent = { inherited: true };
  const child = Object.create(parent);
  child.inherited // true
```

Constructors are just functions, whose `.prototype` property represents the object the instances inherit from:

```
  const foo = new Foo();
  // equals
  const foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
  Foo.call(foo); // execute the constructor with "this" being "foo"
```

Similarily `instanceof` is also just a mechanism on the prototype chain: It checks wether the functions `.prototype` is inside the objects parent chain.

Chain? Yes, objects whose parent also has a parent, also inherit the properties of the parents parent. So to create a "class" that inherits another "class", we have to set the classes `.prototype`s parent to the superclasses `.prototype`. That could be done with

```
  Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

because `new Foo` returns an object whose parent is `Foo.prototype`, therefore Bar instances inherit `Bar.prototype` which inherits `Foo.prototype`.

<sub>¹ The "parent object" is officially called "object prototype", I tried to avoid the possible confusion between the objects prototype and the function objects prototype property</sub>

---

Although this method works, you also execute the constructor of `Foo` on something that is not really an instance (well technically yes, but not conceptually). There are (better) alternatives, e.g. creating instance without executing the constructor:

```
  Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

or directly setting the objects parent:

```
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar.prototype, Foo.prototype);
```

Or, if you use `class` syntax:

```
 class Bar extends Foo {
   //...
 }
```

Comment: Did you just write all this stuff from memory? Alright bro, +1

Comment: @medet yup, not the first time I've explained these things ... :)